# Undefined step при запуске тестов на русском

Tags: java, cucumber

Пытаюсь писать тесты на русском в cucumber java.
Есть .feature файл со следующим содержанием:

```
# language: ru

Функционал: Пользователь может войти в систему введя валидные значения.

  Сценарий: : Пользователь входит в систему введя валидные данные
    Допустим Я нахожусь на loginPage
    Когда Я ввожу валидные логин и пароль
      И Я нажимаю кнопку SignIn
    Тогда Я вхожу на overviewPage

И реализация steps в виде:
@Допустим("^Я нахожусь на loginPage$")
    public void я_нахожусь_на_LoginPage() throws Throwable {
        loginPage.goToLoginPage();
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Когда("^Я ввожу валидные логин и пароль$")
    public void я_ввожу_валидные_логин_и_пароль() throws Throwable {
        $(loginPage.loginPageLoginField).setValue(loginPage.userLogin);
        $(loginPage.loginPagePasswordField).setValue(loginPage.userPassword);
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @И("^Я нажимаю кнопку SignIn$")
    public void я_нажимаю_кнопку_SignIn() throws Throwable {
        loginPage.clickOnSignInButton();
        throw new PendingException();
    }
```

но когда запускаю на выполнение получаю:

```
Undefined step: Допустим  Я нахожусь на loginPage
Undefined step: Когда  Я ввожу валидные логин и пароль
Undefined step: И  Я нажимаю кнопку SignIn
Undefined step: Тогда  Я вхожу на overviewPage
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а как именно вы запускаете этот тест?

Comment: запускаю в intellij IDEA run 'Feature'. Если тоже самое но на английском - всё работает.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте создать вот такой класс, там где у вас живут тесты

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"<путь к файлам feature>"},
        glue = {"<имя пакета где лежат steps>"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}
)
public class RunIntegrationTest {
}
```

И запустите его.

**Дополнение**

У **cucumber** есть проблема, что нельзя запускать тесты, которые использую русскую аннотацию. Такие тесты можно запустить исключительно через класс, который описан выше.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, решил сам. Всё решилось после того как в edit configuration прописал путь в glue.